# Fancybox is not showing from Server side call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I have to show fancybox from server side. I have written a javascript method and called that method in ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript in asp.net button click

Here is my code behind

```
 protected void btnSaveAndAddConcern_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "fancybox", "callFancyBox();", true);
    }
```

and this is my javascript function

```
 function callFancyBox() {
            $("#fancybox").attr("href", "/Agent/AddCampConcernPopup.aspx").fancybox({
                  'width': 550,
                  'height': 200,
                  'type': 'iframe',
                  'title': ''
              }).trigger("click");
          }
```

function is called but fancybox does not open. This javascript function works fine when i call it from client side. but when i call it from code behind fancybox never shows. I inspect the errors in console and it shows this error after calling from server side

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined"

I have jquery 1.10.2 and fancybox version 1.3.4

Again, fancybox is working perfectly when i call it from client side but issue is with server side calling.

Comment: Is `#fancybox` `runat="server"` ?

Comment: no. #fancybox is a simple <a> tag. like this

<a href="#" id="fancybox"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you add

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ajax", "callFancyBox()", true);
```

in place of

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "fancybox", "callFancyBox();", true);
```

Also Add by class not ID so you can pass one function to many as shown below

```
 $(document).ready(function () { //this line you have to add for initiate script so it will solve your undefined error
            $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                type: 'iframe'                   
            });
 }
```

Comment: This is a javascript function that is called from server side . How can i put that funcation in $(document).ready(). 
if i put function directly in $(document).ready(), it will call automatically when page loads, but i need to invoke the method by button click from server side

Comment: Just keep function callFancyBox() in side the $(document).ready(function () {... .. it will solve your problem..

Answer (score 1):

Use `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` instead of `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`.

Try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "fancybox", "callFancyBox();", true);
```

Comment: I tired this code. now it is showing this console error...

Uncaught ReferenceError: callFancyBox is not defined

Comment: Where have you defined this function ?  Put this after body tag.

Comment: This page is inherited from a Master page. Function is written inside content place holder of content page and that content place holder is written in body of Master page.

Comment: But you can move the function to end of body so it will not cause any error.

Comment: I put the function in following places

 In Master page body tag : does not call,
 In Content page Place Holder : does not call,
 In Master page Head tag : function called but result is same, fancybox does not open

Comment: Put it in content page right before closing tag `</asp:Content>`.

Comment: Yes, i put it right before the closing tag </asp:Content>. But it does not call